# How to change color of hint in error state?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Here is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:errorEnabled="true">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Login*"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to change hint color in error state. Now I have this:

[image]

How can I change the color of hint from gray to red in error state?

There is many similar questions, but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What methods have you tried?

Actually, to change just the error message color, you can set textColorError in your theme (and also set colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated for the general widget and hint text color).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/control_normal</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/control_activated</item>
    <item name="textColorError">@color/error</item>
    <!-- other styles... -->
</style>
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- ... -->

</application>
```

In addition, you can also create a custom style which uses @android:style/TextAppearance as parent in your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_500</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And use it in your TextInputLayout widget:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">
```